# Compilation issue in Visual Studio 12 Professional with a C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

The project worked fine in Visual Studio 2010, and we upgraded to Visual Studio 2012; however, now it does not compile.

We get the following error:

> Error 2   Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed    PROJECT_NAME

Does anyone how to solve this issue?

I am on Windows 2008 R2 SP1 with .NET 4.5 installed. I did not install .NET 4 directly, I used the .NET 4.5 installer.

Comment: Have you followed the steps described in the error message?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I don't have .net. I installed direct .net 4.5 when I install my station 2-3 days ago.

Comment: Obviously your project uses the Windows SDK for .NET 4. Did you install that?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have .net 4.5 do I have any other option for make it work.

Comment: Install the SDK. What's so hard to understand here?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have installed Visual Studio 2012 SDK (x86) - (English) but it's still not solved

Comment: The error message refers to the Windows SDK, not the Visual Studio SDK.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth please one more help. It's look like I need win8 sDK when i have 2008 r2. am I right. Do I need win7 sdk or win8 sdk.

Comment: I don't think that you need any of those as you have Windows 2008. That's not Windows 7 and not Windows 8.

Comment: I thing 2008 and Win7 use same codebase so maybe I need win7 sdk but another confusion is \v8.0A maybe this is about win8. I am confused a lot now.

Comment: Windows 8 has been released two weeks ago. Rest assured that v8.0A doesn't refer to Windows 8

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this by installing "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx

I was confused by the title - I'm on Windows 7 - but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Solution pointed by Mark Rainey worked for us:
http://www.markrainey.me/2013/02/setting-up-build-machine.html

> Changing sdk version
>
> ```
> Go to "Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1" from the Start menu
> Select "Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt" and enter
> > cd Setup
> > WindowsSdkVer -version:v7.1
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This worked for me on my Windows 7 build server after it started failing while looking for ngen.exe while building one of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was when clicking on `Properties` on the solution for the `Active(Debug)` configuration, the configuration for my projects were set to `Release`. Changed it to `Debug`, rebuilt and the build error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

After 2013 now msbuild is part of VS.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/

On my case I had to change the msbuild path after I installed VS2015 to

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\

Answer (score 0):

"I fixed this by installing "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx"

This solution by user489998 worked fine on Windows server 2008 R2 as well.